# php if else convert value

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i have value from database, when the data show 1, it will be a, when the data show 2, it will be b, ....

```
CREATE TABLE `jurnal`(
`id` INT(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`month` INT(2)NOT NULL,
`year` INT(4)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`))ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

the value from database like:

```
id=1 month=3 year=2012
```

i want make the value from `month` using 'if else' if work, to make

```
if 1, it will be a, if 2, it will be b, ... and so on to 12
```

the output data that I wish would like

```
c, 2012 not 3, 2012
```

thank's before

Comment: If 1 will be 'a' then INT dont  support chracter data type . First change data type !!!

Comment: Do you really want "a" or "January"?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the `CHAR` function to render out any character you like:

```
SELECT CHAR(96 + month)
```

ASCII 97 is `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE if you want add some logic in you condition

`SELECT CASE month 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'a'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'b' 
        ELSE '?' 
        END;
 FROM  jurnal`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Thanks